# WM_LBUTTONDOWN & WM_LBUTTONUP not received

Tags: windows, winapi

I created toplevel window, but for unknown reasons my WNDPROC does not receive **WM_LBUTTONDOWN/WM_LBUTTONUP** nor **WM_MOUSEMOVE** messages.

Any suggestions?

Relevant code:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
Wc.cbSize = 48;
Wc.cbWndExtra = 80;
Wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(1002));
Wc.style = CS_GLOBALCLASS | CS_DBLCLKS;
Wc.lpszClassName = Ici[dItemIndex].sInit;
Wc.lpfnWndProc = Ici[dItemIndex].wInit;

RegisterClassExW(&Wc);

g_hRuler1 = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
                            RULER_CONTROL,
                            L"",
                            WS_POPUP|WS_VISIBLE|0x1,
                            100 ,100, 40, RECTHEIGHT(g_rScreen),
                            NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);

LRESULT WINAPI Ruler_Window(HWND hWindow, UINT uWindow, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uWindow == WM_GETMINMAXINFO)
    {
        goto DODEFAULT;
    }

    if (uWindow == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        g_pGRI = RULER_ALLOCATE();

        RULER_SET_POINTER(hWindow, (LONG_PTR)g_pGRI);

        return 1L;
    }

    g_pGRI = RULER_GET_POINTER(hWindow);

    g_pGRI->hWindow = hWindow;

    switch(uWindow)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            return Ruler_OnCreate(wParam, lParam);
        }

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            return Ruler_OnPaint(wParam, lParam);
        }

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            return Ruler_OnMouseMove(wParam, lParam);
        }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            return Ruler_OnDestroy(wParam, lParam);
        }

    case WM_SETCURSOR:
        {
            return Ruler_OnSetCursor(wParam, lParam);
        }

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            return Ruler_OnLeftButtonDown(wParam, lParam);
        }

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        {
            return Ruler_OnLeftButtonUp(wParam, lParam);
        }

    case GM_SETINDICATORS:
        {
            return Ruler_OnSetIndicators(wParam, lParam);
        }

DODEFAULT:
    return DefWindowProcW(hWindow, uWindow, wParam, lParam);
    }

}
```

Spy++ messages of window after left button click.

[image]

Comment: Your class names in the `RegisterClassExW` and `CreateWindowExW` calls do not seem to match.

Comment: Ici[1].sInit = RULER_CONTROL.

Comment: As I already said, they do not seem to match. You should probably add related code to make the sample self-contained.

Comment: I dont have problem with class, i receive WM_CREATE, WM_PAINT, WM_SIZE, but dont WM_LBUTTON....

Comment: Is `g_hRuler1` enabled? If you called `EnableWindow(g_hRuler1,FALSE);` or didn't call `EnableWindow(g_hRuler1,TRUE);` then all input goes to the parent window.

Comment: I added EnableWindow(g_hRuler1,TRUE), without change - still message dont arrive.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you setting `cbSize` to 48 (vs. `sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW)`) and what's with the `0x1` window style?

Comment: 48 = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) and 0x01 - is vertical style for the ruler

Comment: `sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW) == 48`. Sometimes. It certainly doesn't hold for a 64bit build. As a rule of thumb: Every magic number is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Yes, but this is only test for 32 bit.

Comment: While I agree that you've posted _some_ relevant code, I don't think you've posted _all_ relevant code. We need more context to be able to help. I have created a top-level window with the same styles and settings as you, and the three messages you mention all come through.

Comment: What is relevant code? If I posted all code, this is 2000 lines of code in dll and 1000 in exe.

Comment: Relevant code comprises at best a minimal testcase, i.e. the least amount of code that exposes the described behavior. This boils down to an investment at your end of the helpline.

Comment: Again, my wndproc is working, I receive for example WM_CREATE, WM_PAINT messages, so WNDPROC is not problem. I added Spy++ messages of my window.

Comment: You definitely *do* get the mouse move and click messages.  But they are posted to you as WM_NCxxx messages.  In other words, Windows thinks you are clicking and moving in the non-client area of the window.  That's *normally* the border and the caption of a window.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but why?

Comment: I'm going to take a leap and say you aren't passing unhandled messages to `DefWindowProc()` but instead are doing something like `return uMsg - 1;` at the end of your window procedure.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I edited post, see my WNDPROC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem here is that you are most likely not calling `DefWindowProc` from your custom `wndProc` method (`Ruler_Window`).

Your code structure in your `wndProc` is a little... interesting.

You handle the messages you are interested in in a switch statement (with the exception of `WM_NCCREATE`, which is fine), but your switch statement doesn't actually have a `default:` entry... instead you have created a label called `DODEFAULT`, which you only reference once - when the message is `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` you `goto DODEFAULT`.  Ignoring the issue of using a `goto` here, you basically do not handle any messages other than those listed in your code, and more importantly, *you don't pass other messages to the default handler*.

A very quick, very simple rewrite of your `Ruler_Window` method:

```
LRESULT WINAPI Ruler_Window(HWND hWindow, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        g_pGRI = RULER_ALLOCATE();
        RULER_SET_POINTER(hWindow, (LONG_PTR)g_pGRI);
        return DefWindowProcW(hWindow, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    // not sure what g_pGRI is, guessing it's a global?
    // should this actually be passed into the handlers below?
    g_pGRI = RULER_GET_POINTER(hWindow);
    g_pGRI->hWindow = hWindow;

    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        return Ruler_OnCreate(wParam, lParam);

    case WM_PAINT:
        return Ruler_OnPaint(wParam, lParam);

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        return Ruler_OnMouseMove(wParam, lParam);

    case WM_DESTROY:
        return Ruler_OnDestroy(wParam, lParam);

    case WM_SETCURSOR:
        return Ruler_OnSetCursor(wParam, lParam);

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        return Ruler_OnLeftButtonDown(wParam, lParam);

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        return Ruler_OnLeftButtonUp(wParam, lParam);

    case GM_SETINDICATORS:
        return Ruler_OnSetIndicators(wParam, lParam);

    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hWindow, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Note, I also changed the name of the message parameter to be `uMsg`, as it makes reading the code much easier, IMHO.

Comment: Nice catch, in first revision of the code I have default: goto DODEFAULT, but for unknown reason I delete this.

Comment: If I may, I gave you +200 reputation for this.

Comment: Credit should also go to [Jonathan Potter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/506413/jonathan-potter) who [pinpointed the root cause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254433/wm-lbuttondown-wm-lbuttonup-not-received#comment26778035_18254433) some 20 hours ago.

Comment: @Xearinox: To be honest, if you think this answer is useful you should +1 it and accept it, and that's all.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the problem is that you are not calling DefWindowProc for WM_NCCREATE and WM_CREATE. This means that the window is never setting up its client areas, so the messages are coming in as WM_NC*.

You should always pass WM_NCCREATE and WM_CREATE on to DefWindowProc.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not problem. First WM_CREATE working, second from WM_NCCREATE doc: If an application processes this message, it should return TRUE to continue creation of the window

Comment: @Xearinox: Yes, returning TRUE in response to `WM_NCCREATE` means that the call to `CreateWindow` will be "successful". However, by returning TRUE you are stating that "the Non-Client area of the window was created successfully."  This creation is _usually_ best handled by the default handler.  In general, WM_NCCREATE is only handled to initialise custom structures before Windows itself does the actual creation.

Comment: @icabod: I changed on WM_NCCREATE instead return TRUE to goto DODEFAULT but behavior is still same.